# javascript variable scope related hoistring

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

this is my problem.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var name;
        console.log(name);
        name = "abcdefg";
        console.log(name);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this code's output is

[image]

i know that first log have to said undefined because Hoisting.

i already tried refresh and delete cache and don't understand why. please help me.

Comment: What is the question? You already know why this is happening.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Exactly can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is a reserved variable name of the `window`. So when you first access the `name` without overriding it (`var name` does not override), you get the global property `window.name`.

In your case at the first `console.log` you may get something differ `undefined`, but not equal to the `abcdefg`

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var name;
        console.log(name);
        name = "abcdefg";
        console.log(name);
        console.log(window.name);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SurenSrapyan you are right. my window.name value was changed.